# Why does not std::advance return the resulting iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, std

Currently, `std::advance` is designed like this:

```
template< class InputIt, class Distance >
void advance( InputIt& it, Distance n );
```

However, I frequently find myself want something like:

```
template< class InputIt, class Distance >
InputIt advance( InputIt it, Distance n );
```

So, what is the rationale behind the current design? Is this for some performance consideration? Note that `std::next` and `std::prev` do return the resulting iterator.

Comment: I believe this design is required to support input iterators. `std::next` and `std::prev` require forward and bi-directional iterators, correspondingly.

Comment: I believe it didn't occur to them to design it like that.... like many other things.

Comment: IDK. However, in other places, some effort was made to avoid redundant copies of iterators, e.g., post vs. pre increment. So apparently someone considered this a performance issue, as you suggested.

Comment: `std::next` doesn't change an iterator passed to it, it returns another iterator that points to the next element in a collection. This is not an option for an input iterator.

Comment: Note that C++ does not forbid you to write your own `std::advance` or versions on top of it.

Comment: Consider `advance` as the underlying low-level implementation abstraction used by higher-level convenience functions like `next`. There's a place for both of them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no technical reason preventing it to return *a reference* to the input value, and any reasonable compiler should be able to optimize the return value out if it's not used. So they could have done it that way if they wanted to.

I think their choice makes sense from an API design point of view though - `std::prev` and `std::next` take an iterator and return a different iterator pointing to the previous or next element, respectively, *without modifying the input*.

`std::advance` on the other hand modifies the input. If it returned a reference to the input iterator, it might be confused for a function that returns a copy without modifying the input in-place. That could potentially be dangerous.

Note that `std::advance` works with `InputIterator`s, which includes iterators where iteration has side effects (things such as iterators that read from streams), but `std::prev` and `std::next` only work with `ForwardIterator`s, which do not have side effects.

So returning a separate *value* (like `std::prev` and `std::next`) would be a bad idea - you'd end up with two iterators on the same stream, which may affect each other adversely.

Comment: This doesn't make sense as an explanation - you're just repeating obvious facts. The whole answer boils down to "they could have done it but they didn't".

Comment: @BartoszKP They could have done it but they didn't because it would have been a bad idea. My answer explains why it would have been a bad idea.

Comment: For example, the third paragraph is a triviality that applies to *any* function, not only `std::advance`. If `std::prev` took a reference you could say exactly the same thing about it - returning a reference might have been confused for a function that returns copy without modifying the input. Only the paragraph about input and forward iterators (*that you have just added*) is relevant. So, now it seems OK (although I'd remove all other parts as they are only noise and it's hard to find the point, which is only in the 4th paragraph) - I'll remove my comments. Cheers!

Comment: somehow I think std::prev won't work on a ForwardIterator (needs BidirectionalIterator)

Answer (score 1):

The main reason, as indicated in the comments section is that an [InputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator) does not guarantee that after incrementing an iterator, any previous iterators will still be valid:

> InputIterators only guarantee validity for single pass algorithms: once an InputIterator i has been incremented, all copies of its previous value may be invalidated.

Thus if [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) returned a copy the caller could end up with two iterators of which one could be invalid. The interface with a reference indicates that this is not how input iterators should be used.

[`std::prev`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) and [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) on the other hand take a [BidirectionalIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator), which among others, satisfies requirements for a [ForwardIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator):

> Unlike InputIterator and OutputIterator, it can be used in multipass algorithms.

So, you can move an iterator while still holding a copy of its previous position.

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) is a nice table that clearly presents relations between different iterator concepts.

---

Of course one may argue that the caller should be aware of how InputIterator works and should be allowed to have the convenience of choosing a version that suits their current need. An example of such issue was presented by [dyp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420683/dyp) in the comments section: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2353.

Pleasing everyone however always leads to an explosion of the number of methods in an interface.

The link suggests that what is now is a state of a to-be-consensus.